# How to get the laravel view values in the script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

View code:

```
@foreach($showcategories as $showcategory)
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">{{$showcategory->categoryName}}</div>
    <div class="panel-body" ><a href="#" class="checkDeviceCategory">
   {{$showcategory->subCategoryName}}</a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<br/>
@endforeach
```

This is my view code. Here i am returning the fetched db values dynamically. On click with the value of panel body it should alert it.

Script code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.checkDeviceCategory').click(function() {
var value=$(this).val();
alert(value);

});
});
</script>
```

This is my script code I have tried.But here it displays nothing.

Comment: use `text()` .  `var value=$(this).text();` there is no `alue attribute` for `anchor tag` .

Comment: yes ,text() worked.thanks!!

Comment: Glad it help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script on same page, you can try below:
Set value into script using laravel:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkDeviceCategory').click(function() {
        var value = '{{$showcategory->subCategoryName}}';
        alert(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

OR script on different place, Use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.checkDeviceCategory').click(function() {
        var value = $(this).text();
        alert(value);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `text()` . There is no `value attribute` for `anchor tag`

```
 var value = $(this).text();
```

**Script :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkDeviceCategory').click(function() {
      var value = $(this).text();
      alert(value);

   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get anchor tag text by using jquery [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

```
var value = $(this).text();
```

Since it is not value so [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function will not get the anchor tag text.